# How to correctly change my state in my reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have an action that is fetching from an API.

I am fetching the user from my API, and it returns the JSON with and returns with the action and the json values for the user and a progress value.

```
  fetchUser: (userId) => {
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch({ type: Constants.USER_FETCHING });
      let url = 'http://localhost:4001/api/v1/users/'+ userId;
      axios.get(url)
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log('data returned is ' + JSON.stringify(data));
          dispatch({
            type: Constants.GET_USER,
            user: data.user,
            progress: data.progress,
          });
        });
    };
  },
```

Now in my reducer I have to return the state without mutating it:

```
import Constants from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  users: [],
  user: null,
  progress: null,
  fetching: false,
};

const users = (state = initialState, action) => {
    case Constants.USER_FETCHING:
      return {...state, fetching: true};
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.GET_USER:
      return ?????;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default users;
```

How exactly should I be returning the state?

I see examples using Object.assign but not sure how to structure it for my case:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, ????);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Karbaman and Tony answers are correct. Furthermore, the Object spread is compiled to `Object.assign` by default if you're using `babel`, as you can read in the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

To add to those answers, if you want to update the `users` array, you can use the spread transform ([documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-spread/)):

```js
case Constants.GET_USER:
return {
    ...state,
    user: action.user,
    progress: action.progress,
    users: [ ...state.users, action.user ]
};
```

Which will create a new array for users, `concat` it with the existing one, then with the new `user`.

However, if the `user` in the `action` is already within the existing array, it will get duplicated. You can implement a verification to avoid that, or use directly [union](https://lodash.com/docs#union) from `lodash` (if `user` is a `String` or `Number`):

```js
....
    users: union(state.users, [action.user])
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spread operator `...` as you did in your `USER_FETCHING`:

```
case Constants.GET_USER:
    return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user,
        progress: action.progress
    };
```

This creates a new object by first setting the same properties as they currently are on `state`, and then overwrites the `user` and `progress` properties with the new values from the `action`.

Comment: You’d probs also want to set `fetching` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Object.assign, then it will be:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {user: action.user, progress: action.progress});
```

How it works:
Object.assign gets 3 objects:

- {} - empty
- state
- {user: action.user, progress: action.progress}

and merges them into 1 object one by one.

It is important to have empty object ( {} ) as a first argument, because in this case props/values from state will be merged to empty object and you will have a new copy.
If you remove empty object or put *state* as a first argument - in this case everything will be merged to *state* and you will have a mutation instead of copying.

Comment: Is the other example using ...state above mutating state or its just like yours?

Comment: You can use ...state version if you want. I just provided Object.assign version as asked in the question.